# Typescript syntax for a lambda that is triggered from different events

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

Using the serverless framework I have defined a lambda that can be either triggered every hour or via SNS

```
  ...
  functions: {
    fooAction: {
      handler: 'handler.fooAction',
      events: [
        {
          schedule: 'rate(1 hour)',
        },
        {
          sns: {
            topicName: 'fooTopic',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
   ...
  }
  ...
```

What is the correct typescript syntax when defining `fooAction` function?

I have tried

```
import { SNSHandler, ScheduledHandler} from 'aws-lambda';
...
export const fooAction: ScheduledHandler | SNSHandler = async (evt) => { ... };
```

but `evt` resolves to `any`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There seems to be a type `Handler` in aws-lambda sdk, which is generic and can be used for situations like this,

```
import { SNSEvent, EventBridgeEvent, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

const fooHandler: Handler<SNSEvent | EventBridgeEvent<any, any>> = (event) => {
    if ('Records' in event ) {
        // SNSEvent
        const records = event.Records;
        // so something
    } else {
        const { id, version, region, source } = event;
    }
};
```

You can also define your own type based on these two different function types.

```
type CustomEvent = (event: SNSEvent | EventBridgeEvent<"Scheduled Event", any>, context: Context, callback: Callback<void>) => Promise<void> | void
```

And then, use this new type with your lambda function,

```
const fooHandler: CustomEvent = (event) => {
    if ('Records' in event ) {
        // SNSEvent
        const records = event.Records;
        // so something
    } else {
        const { id, version, region, source } = event;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just stumbled across this comment while looking into the same use-case.  Consider creating a lambda function per event source to avoid the if/else logic within your Lambda function.

Comment: I believe `EventBridgeEvent<"Scheduled Event", any>` should be `EventBridgeEvent<"Scheduled Event", string>`. EventBridge seems to JSON.stringify the details.